# HTTP Hello World using node.js

Tags: node.js

I have installed node.js on my server and created the following page on my server called app.js

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

The when I call it I just see the code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have Node.js installed and running your script...? A la `node app.js`?

Comment: Aside: it's generally not advisable to reveal your IP address like this - automated scrapers will sometimes take this information and attempt to compromise your local networks if not protected well enough.

Comment: What happens when you navigate to your server on `http://localhost:3000`?

Comment: now, you are using `nginx`, or `httpd`, instead of `node.js`

Comment: you need close the httpd, and you need  run with `node app.js`

Comment: Node.js is not like PHP. Your web server will not know how to execute node.js code. Instead node.js is like C++ or Java or Python - you create a web server using node.js. So you don't request from `https://173-165-202-193-jacksonville.hfc.comcastbusiness.net/app.js` but instead you request form `ttps://173-165-202-193-jacksonville.hfc.comcastbusiness.net:3000` (because you run your HTTP server on port 3000)

Comment: I strongly suggest you run your node web server on your local PC first before trying to host it. When you are ready to host it you will need to find a web hosting that can run programs not just host PHP files. If you are familiar with Linux look at Azure or AWS if not look at something like Heroku for node.js hosting

Comment: Both Azure and AWS have 1 year free account

Comment: Thank you to all. I think I can go from here.

Comment: How do I close this or acknowledge all the help? Not sure what to do here. Thanks